# No Search Result found/No data available message should be displayed when there are no matching results

Tags: search, uitoolbar, nssearchtoolbaritem

Expected Result:
No Search Result found/No data available message should be displayed when there are no matching results

Actual Result:
Blank page with 0 items displays when are no matching search results